# How to check if the user has bought a subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

in my android app i implemented the in App-Billing, where the user can buy a subscription in the app.
when the user launch the app, i want to check if he has any subscription at all, to decide which content should i show him.
i'm using the latest in-app-billing library `implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'` 
thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

You have two options

1. Create a WebAPI as Google suggest having a separate server which tracks users purchases and communicates with the Google APIs. Refer [LINK](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions).
2. Use Google's InApp billing library to get users subscription.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49422300/9522887) answer. It will give you some idea of In-app purchase workflow.

I also suggest you go through some articles about InApp purchase.

- Tutorial: How to Implement In-app Billing in Android [LINK](https://blahti.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/how-to-add-in-app-billing-in-android-part-1/)
- Article on implementing InApp purchase [LINK](https://android.jlelse.eu/implementing-in-app-billing-in-android-4896232c7d6b).
- How to verify purchase for android app in server side (google play in app billing v3) [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850864/how-to-verify-purchase-for-android-app-in-server-side-google-play-in-app-billin).
- Another SO answer [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437628/google-android-in-app-purchases-content-delivery-how-to-correctly-deliver-cont)
- Another SO answer [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115381/unable-to-get-the-subscription-information-from-google-play-android-developer-ap)
- Code Project Sample [LINK](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1009240/How-to-Implement-Android-In-App-Purchases).

Answer (score 2):

my goal was to find out, if the user has a subscription at all.
i have resolved it like this.

```
    mBillingManager = new BillingManager(this);

    Purchase.PurchasesResult  purchasesResult = mBillingManager.getPurchaseMadeByUser();
    if(purchasesResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && (purchasesResult.getPurchasesList() != null)){
        hasSubscription = true;
    }
```

and everywhere in the app, i check if hasSubscription == true then don't load the ads.

to set up  the In-App Billing in my App, i followed this Tutorial from Google : 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/play-billing-codelab/#0